# Paragraph Indentation in minipage

Tags: indentation, minipage, paragraphs

I am having some trouble with paragraph indentation in a minipage.

Here is my MWE code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
        \justify\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}
        
        \indent My friends, I had not intended to discuss this controversial subject at this particular time. However, I want you to know that I do not shun controversy. On the contrary, I will take a stand on any issue at any time, regardless of how fraught with controversy it might be. You have asked me how I feel about whiskey. All right, here is how I feel about whiskey:
        
        If when you say whiskey you mean the devil’s brew, the poison scourge, the bloody monster, that defiles innocence, dethrones reason, destroys the home, creates misery and poverty, yea, literally takes the bread from the mouths of little children; if you mean the evil drink that topples the Christian man and woman from the pinnacle of righteous, gracious living into the bottomless pit of degradation, and despair, and shame and helplessness, and hopelessness, then certainly I am against it.
        
        But, if when you say whiskey you mean the oil of conversation, the philosophic wine, the ale that is consumed when good fellows get together, that puts a song in their hearts and laughter on their lips, and the warm glow of contentment in their eyes; if you mean Christmas cheer; if you mean the stimulating drink that puts the spring in the old gentleman’s step on a frosty, crispy morning; if you mean the drink which enables a man to magnify his joy, and his happiness, and to forget, if only for a little while, life’s great tragedies, and heartaches, and sorrows; if you mean that drink, the sale of which pours into our treasuries untold millions of dollars, which are used to provide tender care for our little crippled children, our blind, our deaf, our dumb, our pitiful aged and infirm; to build highways and hospitals and schools, then certainly I am for it.
        
        This is my stand. I will not retreat from it. I will not compromise.
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Which gives this output:
[image]

I have tried `\indent` (as is in the example), setting the paragraph indent in the minipage, and including/removing `\\` after the paragraphs. When I include a `\\` before the paragraph, I get an error. I have also tried including the `indentfirst` package, with no success.

Any help is appreciated.

Note: I am using a minipage because it fits in my other document. However, if people know how to indent a whole clump of text (and still have the paragraph indents), that'd be preferred.

Thanks.

Comment: Removing `\justify` should do.  Text in `minipage`s is justified by default.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Wow, that was some classic overthinking on my end. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `\justify` fixes the problem entirely. As Phelype Oleinik commented on the original question, text in a minipage is justified (and indented) by default.